# ember.js seemingly picking the wrong controller for a route

Tags: routes, controller, ember.js

i'm trying to write a little blog app with rails/ember.js. posts can be tagged (using acts-as-taggable-on) and it shall be possible to see a list of all posts with a certain tag by visiting "/t/:tag_name". i'm doing the search with "tagged_with" in the post_controller.rb's index action (called via "find" in the tagged_route.js if i'm not mistaken) and when i visit the page directly (e.g. with "/t/first") everything works fine.

however, when i go to the page of one of the posts and click on the link to one of the tags there, ember.js stays in the post controller (the .js one) while going to the correct address and i get one of the following error messages:

- TypeError: arrangedContent.addArrayObserver is not a function
- TypeError: content.removeArrayObserver is not a function
- TypeError: get(...).objectAt is not a function

i've tried adding

```
controllerFor: function() {
  return EmberBlog.TaggedController;
}
```

to the tagged_route.js, but then the list of found posts on the tag page just remains empty.
soo, does anyone have an idea what i might be doing wrong?

here are the (probably) relevant files:

my router.js:

```
EmberBlog.Router.map(function() {
// default index route to / loading index template
  this.resource("posts", function() { // implicit path and template name (same as route name)
    //this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
  this.resource('tagged', { path: '/t/:tag_name' });
  this.route("about");
});

EmberBlog.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

my tagged_route.js:

```
EmberBlog.TaggedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    Em.Logger.info( params );

    var posts = EmberBlog.Post.find({'tag_name': params.tag_name});
    return posts;
  }//,
  //controllerFor: function() {
  //  return EmberBlog.TaggedController;
  //}
});
```

the index action in my post_controller.rb:

```
def index
  if params[:tag_name]
    posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag_name])
  else
    posts = Post.all
  end
  render json: posts, meta: { total: posts.count }
end
```

my tagged.handlebars:

```
<h2>Tagged Posts</h2>

<div id="posts">
  {{log controller}}
  <ul>
    {{#each post in controller}}
      {{view EmberBlog.PostInListView contentBinding="post"}} //--> <li>{{#linkTo post post}}{{post.title}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
    {{else}}
      Sorry, no posts to display
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

the relevant part of my post.handlebars:

```
...
<div class="taglist">
  <ul class="inline">
    Tags:
    {{#each tag in tagList}}
      <li>{{#linkTo tagged tag}}{{tag}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
    {{else}}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the issue with the help of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341429/ember-typeerror-arrangedcontent-addarrayobserver-is-not-a-function).

the problem was that linkTo didn't trigger the model hook in my TaggedRoute and the TaggedController (an ArrayController) was trying to work with the string passed on by linkTo.

i solved it by making the TaggedController an ObjectController with the computed property postsWithTag

```
EmberBlog.TaggedController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: null,

  postsWithTag: function() {
    var posts = EmberBlog.Post.find({'tag_name': this.get('content')});
    return posts;
  }.property('@content')
});
```

and changing the TaggedRoute to

```
EmberBlog.TaggedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    Em.Logger.info( params );

    var tag = params.tag_name;
    return tag;
  }
});
```

and the tagged.handlebars to

```
<h2>Tagged Posts</h2>

<div id="posts">
  {{log controller}}
  <ul class="unstyled">
    {{#each post in postsWithTag}}
      {{view EmberBlog.PostInListView contentBinding="post"}}
    {{else}}
      Sorry, no posts to display
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```