# Ember -- TypeError: arrangedContent.addArrayObserver is not a function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to build a simple category browser with ember. I have two very simple views. When the user visits `/` they will see a list of all categories and when they click a category in that list they will be directed to `#/10` where 10 is the id.

My problem is that when a user clicks on a category at the `/` route I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: arrangedContent.addArrayObserver is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

didChange: 'arrangedContentArrayDidChange'
```

If I refresh the page at the `#/10` route the proper api call is made to my backend `/api/categories?parent=99`. What could I be doing wrong that is throwing this error during the transition? A full example of my code is below.

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    {{#each category in controller}}
        <p>{{#linkTo 'category' category}}{{ category.name }}{{/linkTo}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<!--this is an array instead of object -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
    {{#each category in controller}}
        <p>{{category.name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('categories', { path : '/' });
    this.resource('category', { path : '/:category_id' });
});

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Category.find();
    }
});

//this is causing the error possibly
    App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params){
            return App.Category.find({parent: params.category_id});
        }
    });

App.CategoryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

// Models
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  category: "categories"
});

App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  parent_id: DS.attr('number')
});
```

**Debug info:**

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.0
```

Comment: I am a little confused. The CategoriesRoute should display a list of your categories, while the CategoryRoute should display the details for one given category? Is this right? Then why are you using the each helper in both handlebars templates? I would suspect that the CategoryRoute just shows the payload of one category.

Comment: Both templates show a list of categories. The single **category** template shows a list of categories with the parent_id = to params.category_id. This is why I am using App.Category.find({parent: params.category_id}); to populate the model. And why things are most likely going haywire.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** After writing this i realized that you probably did not get the model hook right. This hook is called when you are entering your app via url. It converts the URL into an appropriate model and transition with this model into the Route. **I guess you thought that this model() hook would be called with the arguments of {{#linkTo}}? This is not the case!**

This does not work because you are passing a single model to your #linkTo helper in your template. So Ember wants to set this single object as content of your ArrayController. This causes your error. And your model hook returns an array. **Rule of Thumb: You should always pass the same data structure to #linkTo, which you are returning in your model hook.**

Therefore i would suggest to use an event instead of linkTo and do the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    {{#each category in controller}}
        <p {{action 'showParentCategory' category}}>{{category.name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Category.find();
    },
    events: {
      showParentCategory : function(parentCategory){
        var cats = App.Category.find({parent: parentCategory.get("category_id")});
        this.transitionTo("category", cats);
      }
    }
});
```

**What have i done here?**

1. I created an action called "showParentCategory".
2. As this is an action with is about routing, i am handling this event in your CategoriesRoute. As you see, events/action handlers are declared in the events property of your route.
3. I am performing the same logic there as in your model hook and then i am calling manually the transitinTo with the fetched categories.

**UPDATE: How to serialize**
By implementing serialize, you are telling Ember what to put into your url.

```
App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return App.Category.find({parent: params.category_id});
    },
    serialize : function(models){
        var first = models.objectAt(0);
        return {
            category_id : first.get("parentId")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is looking really good but I am getting an error. SyntaxError: function statement requires a name showParentCategory : function(parentCategory){

Comment: yep that works, just noticed it too. Also have to change .get("category_id") to .get("id"). One thing that seems incorrect is that each category is now linked to #/undefined instead of #/10 is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Also if I add the same logic to the **category** template I get the following error Error: Nothing handled the event 'showParentCategory'. So it seems that this solution limits the ability to drill down further. It might be ideal to remove the category template all together.

Comment: The action can be handled by the view, controller or route that are connected with your template. When your category template is active, you are in a completely separate path in your mappings.

Comment: thanks, how would I go about getting the parent category id into the route? So my urls are #/10 instead of #/undefined? It does not seem that this.transitionTo() has this capability.

Comment: Regarding the effect of #/undefined. You would have to tell ember how to serialize the model implementing the serialize hook. Normally ember does this for you by searching for a id property on your model and put it into the dynamic segment. But i do not see an id property on your model?

Comment: So easiest would be that the models posess an attribute called 'id'. This is what gets put automagically into the URL.

Comment: My model does include an id, you are not allowed to add an id directly to the model definition. Ember throws an error. My rest backend returns this id however. If I use ember in it's normal way the id is placed in the url correctly. I think the fact that we are doing this out of the ordinary is causing the issue. Gotta have that id tho :(

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to pass a variable to the url with the **action** tag

Comment: thanks, I was getting an error that first is undefined, but I was able to remove that and replace the return code to this category_id : models.query.parent... Everything seems to be working ok with this approach.

Comment: Shall i update my answer with something or do you think that it will help others in its current form??

Comment: This is the working example I currently have http://pastie.org/6452793, If you see any more room for improvement please do advise :) Specifically I am wondering if my App.Router.map is correct and if there is unecessary redundancy with return App.Category.find({parent: category.category_id}); in the Category and Application Routes

Answer (score 0):

If you do #each over a numeric value instead of doing it on an array content in your template, this issue occurs.

I had a numeric value count in my 'poll' model . I was iterating like,

{{#each poll in content.count}}
{{/each}}

I think, we have to use #each only on ember arrays.